# css/javascript return the id of the element inside it

Tags: javascript, css

This is no doubt super simple, i tried googling how to access the id of an element but it wasnt finding anything in the same context of what i need.

Here is my simple code

```
<td class="row">Carebears
    <a href="" onmouseover="newImage('images/my_image'); change_title(this.innerHTML);">
         <span class="snapshot"><img src="images/snapshot.png" width="16" height="12" alt=""/></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

Ok so what was initially happening here was when you mouseover the text it would show the new image in another div and it would show the innerHTML (carebears in this case) as the title. This worked great but i want to change this so now the image shows when you hover over an image beside the text.

As you can imagine from the code now it shows the picture as the title since that is the inner html now. There might be a better way of doing it but what i was thinking was i would add the title of the image as the id like this

```
<img src="images/snapshot.png" width="16" height="12" alt="" id="Carebears"/>
```

Or even the Alt tag would be an appropiate place to put it but i cannot even after googling a lot find out a way to pass the inner id like this:

```
change_title(this.innerHTML);
```

i want to do something like this:

```
change_title(this.id);
```

or this

```
change_title(this.innerHTML.id);
```

but im not too familiar with this so i have no idea of the structure, i would like to avoid having to add Jquery just for this one simple thing since i didnt need it anywhere else so just plain javascript would be preferable

Comment: Why no simply use html `title` attribute. e.g: `<a title="some text" ></a>` ?

Comment: Please explain clearly what you want to do...

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I have a function change_title(this.innerHTML) and i would like to pass to it the title inside the TD which is carebears.

Whats happening is there another div and as you rollover a row it shows an image and the title. The image is working but i cant figure out how to pass Carebear into the function to display the title

Comment: Could you provide either a Fiddle or your javascript code? [or both]